# Should I capitalise only part of a brand’s title?

Tags: capitalization

When I use only part of a brand’s name or the title of a company, should I be capitalising that word? For example, when referring to the Environment Agency, if I were to just call them the Agency, would the A be uppercase?

Comment: Capitalization is not grammar.

Comment: Related: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/111862/capitalization-of-school-as-an-adjective

Answer (score 1):

Nouns in English are capitalized if they denote a particular thing, but not if they are generic.

> I've been working at this agency eight years.
>
> I've been working at the [Central Intelligence] Agency, well, I can't tell you anything more.

In this case it's a judgment call whether "agency" is being used generically, or as an abbreviated form of "Environment Agency."  Which is why you sometimes see references to the College (a particular college within a university) or the college (the college I attend); or the church (that I attend) or the Church (the Church Universal, or the Catholic Church, with "Universal" or "Catholic" omitted).